# Google Apps Script Q - In Sheets is it possible to setFormula (SUM) where cells to sum change depending on row?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a function which will setFormula to sum values of 2 cells. The formula would need to change depending on the row being worked on.

For example:

- if working in Row 8 of the sheet, the formula will be set as "SUM=E8-D8"
- if working in Row 9 of the sheet, the formula will be set as "SUM=E9-D9"
  and so on, ad infinitum. So basically how copying a formula down a column works. I can't just pre-fill the formula down the column because of another function related to copying data to another sheet.

I have a function that will set the formula in the first useable row, but can't figure out if possible to modify it to work as described above.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  
  if (row > 7 && col == 4) {
    insertCurrentTime(e.range.offset(0, 1)); // This sets the value in Column E
    insertDurationFormula(e.range.offset(0, 2)); //This sets the formula in Column F
  }
}

function insertCurrentTime(cell) {
  cell.setValue(new Date());
}

function insertDurationFormula(cell) {
  cell.setFormula("=SUM(E8-D8)");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

You need to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to incorporate the cell row number into the string argument of the `setFormula` function.

```
let crow = cell.getRow();
cell.setFormula(`=SUM(E${crow}-D${crow})`);
```

Please modify `insertDurationFormula` as it is suggested in my solution.

---

### Solution:

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  
  if (row > 7 && col == 4) {
    insertCurrentTime(e.range.offset(0, 1)); // This sets the value in Column E
    insertDurationFormula(e.range.offset(0, 2)); //This sets the formula in Column F
  }
}

function insertCurrentTime(cell) {
  cell.setValue(new Date());
}

function insertDurationFormula(cell) {
  let crow = cell.getRow(); // new code
  cell.setFormula(`=SUM(E${crow}-D${crow})`); // modified
}
```

Comment: Thanks yet again, @Marios! I didn't come across template literals in any of my googling. More to read up on. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: That works great @Marios. Thanks. One follow up Q though. What if I wanted to use this to sum down the column instead? So working in row 9 would set formula =SUM(E9-E8) and then for row 10 would set formula =SUM(E10-E9)

I'm reading through the link you sent, but I'm afraid for now this is over my head.

Comment: Try to replace the **second** `crow` with `crow-1`. Essentially: ``=SUM(E${crow}-D${crow-1})`` @AndrewHarrell

Comment: Thanks! @Marios, I don't think that's quite it. I suspected there was a -1 in there though. For this version I would want to sum cells in the same column. The first would be =SUM(E9-E8) and next down would be =SUM(E10-E9)

Comment: Sorry, then `=SUM(E${crow}-E${crow-1})` @AndrewHarrell

Comment: Awesome! I actually tried that before I asked again, but it didn't work the first time. Glad my thinking was in the right direction. Thanks again @Marios